# Issue with XJC generated classes

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a xsd as follows

```
  <xs:element name="package">
     .....
       <xs:element name="package">
        .....
          <xs:element name="package">
            ......
           </xs:element>
        </xs:element>
     </xs:element>
```

All  the three packages has different fields. I am trying to generate the classes using `XJC`. It is giving code with inner classes which is compilatin error, because it has the same name inside.
I tried renaming the classes using bindings.My binding file is

```
<jaxb:bindings 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    version="2.1">
    <jaxb:globalBindings/>
    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="CoveragesWithIIRolesresponse.xsd">
            <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='package']">
                    <jaxb:class name="Fault2"/>
            </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

It is giving error saying too many target nodes. How to resolve this issue
Please help me on this

**Update** : if i put `multiple="true"` in my bindings file it is replacing in all the places which leads to same compilation error

Answer (score 1):

Do you think its a good xsd design to do it this way.
Maybe its better to define a single complex-type named "package" with all fields marked as choice and just work with element references within a main element. "MainPackage" or what ever

In this case JaxBinding creates just one class for the type "package".

Take a look at Salami Slice or Venetian Blind design. 
These xsd designs work very well with JaxB because they are more related to object oriented structures and their associations.

Maybe another solution is the usage of different target namespaces of the package element.
In this case the qualified classname of the Package type changes according to the namespace. But in my opinion this is also not a good design.